# How to set encoding for bundle?

Tags: java

I use properties for i18n. If I specify non-English locale:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n/Messages", new Locale("tr", "TR"));
```

I see the message with wrong encoding:

```
ÐÑÐ¸Ð²ÐµÑ!
```

How to set the correct encoding?

Comment: What is the encoding of your bundle file? How do you output this message?

Comment: The encoding is UTF-8. I print it through `System.out.println(title);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem:** By default ISO 8859-1 character encoding is used for reading content of properties file, so if the file contains any character beyond ISO 8859-1 then it will not be processed properly.

**First solution:**
Process the properties file to have content with ISO 8859-1 character encoding by using [native2ascii - Native-to-ASCII Converter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/native2ascii.html)

*What **native2ascii** does:* It converts all the non-ISO 8859-1 character in their equivalent \uXXXX. This is a good tool because you need not to search the \uXXXX equivalent of special character.

Usage for UTF-8: `native2ascii -encoding utf8 e:\a.txt e:\b.txt`

If you use Eclipse then you will notice that it implicitly converts the special character into \uXXXX equivalent. Try copying

> 会意字 / 會意字

into a properties file opened in Eclipse.

**Second solution:** Create a custom `ResourceBundle.Control` class which can be used with `ResourceBundle` to read properties in any given encoding scheme. You may want to use an already created and shared [CustomResourceBundleControl](https://github.com/hagrawal7/CustomResourceBundleControl).
Use it as below:

```
ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("i18n/Messages", new CustomResourceBundleControl("UTF-8"));
```